# logic of branch like power amplifier

Tags: amplifier, rf

There  is an amplifier idea shown below.
where we input a signal divide it and amplify each branch.
Then we add the signals together using combiner.
but if we look at the math we put 5dBm signal divide it so each branch is 2dBm then we have 10dB amplifier so it's 12dBm.
then we add branched together and get 15dBm
So for mathematically we have the same effect as we would use only one amplifier  5+10=15.
What is the advantage of this method?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not stated in your question, but assumed by me, is that the amplifiers are nominally identical, and are being used in an impedance matched system.

If we had one +10 dB amplifier capable of +15 dBm output, then it would be the same, at least as far as power gain is concerned.

However, those 10 dB amplifiers in your drawing are only producing +12 dBm.

Likely the whole point of the circuit is that the available amplifiers are not capable of generating + 15 dBm.

Even if the amplifiers are physically capable of producing + 15 dBm, operating them at lower output power will result in significantly less intermodulation distortion. If the amplifiers are operating well below their limiting power, then the improvement will be 6 dBc (signal drops 3 dB, intermod distortion products drop 9 dB). The improvement could be much more if the amplifiers are near to their power limit.

There may be other improvements, depending on the quality of the amplifiers and the phasing of the power split/combine.

If the splitter and combiner create a 180 phase difference between the amplifiers, then their 2nd harmonic distortion will be cancelled, to the extent that the distortion is consistent between the amplifiers.

If the splitter and combiner create a 90 degree phase difference between the amplifiers, then the signals reflected off their S11 and S22 will be cancelled at the combiners, and their apparent impedance match to the system will be improved, to the extent that their mismatch is consistent between amplifiers.

Answer (score 8):

This is often used in high power RF amplifiers where each amplifier stage is a pair of transistors in a transformer coupled push-pull arrangement.

The individual amplifiers are limited in power because unlike an audio amplifier you can't just parallel transistors for more power so they basically parallel the whole amplifier stages instead, with [power dividers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson_power_divider) and transformers splitting and recombining the signals while maintaining impedance matching.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some reason on the top of my head.

Often you have saturation issue. This allows you to reduce by 3dB the signal of your amplifier which can help with linearity.

This topology is also often use when you want a low power and high power mode. The two amplifier don't always have the same gain.

Finally, having them in parallel makes them less noisy (compare to a more powerful amplifier).

Comment: I don't think that configuration reduces noise. Consider each amplifier outputs a certain noise power. a) The combiner reduces the power of each output signal by 3dB, then adds the two together as power gaining 3dB => same noise, or b) Two lots of noise enter the combiner. The correlated noise ends up in the output, the uncorreltated noise ends up in the combiner's difference port (the resistor of a Wilky) => same noise, or c) on noise figure - the initial splitter reduces the amplifier inputs by 3dB so increases their NF by 3 dB, regained in the final combiner => same noise figure.

Comment: That's fair! My idea was more that a lower power amplifier can usually be built with better noise figure spec.